# Select query using Prepared Statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I do not know what is wrong in my code. Following are the conditions in my code given below:

1. I will enter the customer id in the jTextField
2. After Entering the customer id then in the Database it will search relative information of that customer id (customer_id,customer_name,customer_contact).
3. After Collecting relative information of that particular customer id, it will display on the jTextField.

These is my code given below:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public abstract class customer_details extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JTextField textFieldId;
JTextField textFieldId1;
JTextField textFieldId2;
JTextField textFieldId3;    
JLabel l1;
JLabel l2;
JLabel l3;
JLabel l4;
JLabel l5;
JButton b1,b2;
Container c = getContentPane();
customer_details()
{
    super("Shree Datta Digambar");
    setBounds(140,250,777,555);
    c.setLayout(null);
    textFieldId = new JTextField();        
    textFieldId1 = new JTextField();
    textFieldId2 = new JTextField();
    textFieldId3 = new JTextField();
    this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    l1 = new JLabel("Update Customer Details:-");
    l2 = new JLabel("Customer Id");
    l3 = new JLabel("Customer Id");
    l4 = new JLabel("Name");
    l5 = new JLabel("Contact");
    l1.setBounds(10,10,340,20);
    l2.setBounds(10,20,140,70);
    l3.setBounds(10,100,140,70);
    l4.setBounds(100,100,140,70);
    l5.setBounds(270,100,140,70);
    textFieldId.setBounds(10,70,70,20);         
    textFieldId1.setBounds(10,160,70,20); 
    textFieldId2.setBounds(100,160,150,20); 
    textFieldId3.setBounds(270,160,90,20); 
    b1 = new JButton("Ok");
    b1.setBounds(100,70,50,20);   
    b2 = new JButton("Update");
    b2.setBounds(380,160,90,20);  
    c.add(b1);
    c.add(b2);
    c.add(l1);
    c.add(l2);
    c.add(l3);
    c.add(l4);
    c.add(l5);
    c.add(textFieldId);
    c.add(textFieldId1);
    c.add(textFieldId2);
    c.add(textFieldId3);       
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);                
    b1.addActionListener(this);               
    b2.addActionListener(this);
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    customer_details eeap=new customer_details() {};
}
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{               
    System.out.println("You clicked the button");             
    if(e.getSource()==b1)
    {
        try 
        {
            Connection con;                
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Dalvi");                                       
            java.sql.Statement st = con.createStatement();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT customer_id,customer_name,customer_contact FROM customer_details WHERE customer_id = ?");                          
            ps.setString(1,textFieldId.getText());
            ResultSet rs1=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs1.next())
            {                   
                textFieldId1.setText(rs1.getString(1));
                textFieldId2.setText(rs1.getString(2));
                textFieldId3.setText(rs1.getString(3));   
            }                    
            textFieldId.setText("");
        }
        catch (SQLException s) 
        {
            System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Enter the Detail Correctly");
        }
    }  
}
```

}

Comment: At least debug through the code...

Comment: What happens contrary to what you expect to happen?

Comment: And the result of your debug was... at least a stacktrace, maybe?

Comment: What to do now can you tell me ?

Comment: executeQuery() should be called before you try and read a ResultSet object.. let alone assign something to rs1 result set first. and remove "customer_id = ' ?'" <-- extra space

Comment: When there is a problem, then you must include the error message, or at least explain why the problem is not doing what you expect. You're making it a lot harder for people to help you if the only thing you say is "It doesn't work, here's my code".

Comment: Refrain from use `null` layouts. You do not control the factors that affect the size requirements/decisions for components that will change their sizes on different platforms/os's. You might also like to read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it'll make you code more readable for others ;)

Comment: @EdwardM.B. Still Not Working...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the query (formatting added to improve readability, but is inconsequential to the issue):

```
SELECT customer_id,customer_name,customer_contact 
FROM   customer_details 
WHERE  customer_id = ' ?'
```

By surrounding the `?` with single quotes (`'`), you've turned it in to an SQL character literal. This way, JDBC does **not** recognize it as a special character, and cannot bind it. If you remove them, JDBC will be able to bind properly (and will take care of the datatypes too):

```
SELECT customer_id,customer_name,customer_contact
FROM   customer_details 
WHERE  customer_id = ?
```

Comment: Stil not working.
line no 85 i am getting error as 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at customer_details.actionPerformed(customer_details.java:85)

Comment: It is my stupidity guys.
I just done some silly mistakes in coding but after realizing all thing again i come to know my mistake.

Comment: Thanks to Luiggi Mendoza,Ingo Bürk,Edward M.B.,Jesper, MadProgrammer,Mureinik
For your all contribution.